# Socket stuck usinng python

Tags: python-3.x, loops, sockets, while-loop

I have one query related to socket programming using Python.
I am running while loop upto some specific time but this loop is stuck after once time call and not terminating because the socket is somewhere stuck. I am also closing the socket after using socket every time, but it does not work. My code is given below.
Can anybody help me how to fix this issue without using 'os._exit(0)' because after while loop I need to continue program. I don't want to exist from program. i just want to exit from while loop after specific time....

```
def received_status_Frame(a,b):       

    connn,addr=a,b
    message=connn.recv(4096).decode()
    connn.close()
t=10
while (time.time()-start_time<t):
    PORT = 12345
    s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET,socket.SO_REUSEADDR,1)
    s.bind(('',PORT))
    s.listen()
    print ("before the try accept")
    conn,address=s.accept()
    threading.Thread(target=received_status_Frame,args=(conn,address)).start()
```

Comment: are you able to use a select for your socket?
I'll post some github projects i made for school assignments on sockets in python: https://github.com/andre-motta/tpfinal-redes and this next one is a regular socket server without the select library: https://github.com/andre-motta/tp2-redes/blob/master/dcc023c3.py

Comment: The select interface is good because it deals easily with socket handling, both input and output related.

This is a good example on how to handle a socket: https://steelkiwi.com/blog/working-tcp-sockets/

Comment: What do you mean when you say that the socket is "stuck" ? Does your code stop executing at a specific line, and if so, on what line?

Comment: @ Metareven it stops after once time execution  of "received-status-Frame" finction